# How to access values within a Linq .ToList() using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, linq, list, html-agility-pack

I apologize because I'm still in the processes of learning Linq and HtmlAgilityPack, but I'm trying to assign Title and Link to already created string values. In other words, how do I access the values of this .ToList()?

Below is my code:

```
string imgTitle;
string imgLink;

private void getCaption(string txt)
{

    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml("<html><head></head><body>" + txt + "</body></html>");
    if (htmlDoc != null)
    {
        var elements = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//img[@src]").Select(img => new
        {
            Link = img.Attributes["src"].Value,
            Title = img.Attributes["alt"].Value

        }).ToList();
    }
    imgTitle = elements[0]["Title"];  //I thought i could do this
```

Sorry for a stupid question but I haven't seen any good explanation out there as to How Linq works and the ToList function. When I print elements[0] I get both values like this,    {Link = www.link.url, Title = Some title}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imgTitle = elements[0].Title;
```

basically when you do

```
new
{
    Link = img.Attributes["src"].Value,
    Title = img.Attributes["alt"].Value

}
```

you are creating an anonymous object with 2 properties.

The list is a list of this anonymous object.

`elements[0]` gives you the first object. And you can access the 2 properties with `elements[0].Link` and `elements[0].Title`

Answer (score 1):

What you really have in elements is a list of an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) that have two properties, so you can access to the `Title` as follow:

```
 imgTitle = elements[0].Title;
```